# Prisma .findUnique() error: Unknown arg `email` in where.email for type userWhereUniqueInput. Did you mean `id`

Tags: postgresql, prisma, supabase

I'm new to Prisma so bear with me. I have a (Postgres) DB on Supabase and I have the following model:

```
model user {
  created_at DateTime? @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  email      String    @unique
  id         BigInt    @id @default(autoincrement())
}
```

As you can see, email is set to unique. However, when I try to query it with `.findUnique()` like so:

```
const data = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
        email: user.email
    }
})
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: 
Invalid `prisma.user.findUnique()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    email: 'johndoe@gmail.com'
    ~~~~~
  }
}

Unknown arg `email` in where.email for type userWhereUniqueInput. Did you mean `id`? Available args:
type userWhereUniqueInput {
  id?: BigInt
}
```

The table is currently empty, so I am expecting to get back an empty array. But instead, I get this error. If I run the query as `.findMany()` I get the empty array and no error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you run `prisma generate`?

Comment: @some-user :facepalm: That was it! I somehow missed that step. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As confirmed in the comments,

```
prisma generate
```

was missing.

The command is necessary after each schema change to make prisma aware of it.

Comment: Thanks again. I was running `npx prisma db pull` after each config change. I didn't realize that I also needed to run `npx prisma generate` as well.